# Mongo - find records having same data irrespective of the case

Tags: sql, mongodb, database, nosql

I have a user collection which has an email field. I have a unique constraint on email. I just found out that my users are able to enter the following two same emails with different cases

```
hello.java@xxx.com
HELLO.JAVA@XXX.COM
```

I want to query my collection to get how many records could be there in the db that has the above mentioned problem.

Please help me with this query

I could do `{"email":/hello.java/}` but that is possible if I knew that this email was the one which was entered twice. Now the problem is I want to know which all emails are there that have redundant entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` to get the list of duplicated emails:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // Project the lower-cased version of each doc's email field
    {$project: {email: {$toLower: '$email'}}},
    // Group them by email and get a count of each
    {$group: {_id: '$email', count: {$sum: 1}}},
    // Include the ones with a count > 1
    {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}
])
```